# Python: How do I write a xls file line-by-line through a loop?

Tags: python

I currently have a for-loop running about 3000 iterations, and at the end of the loop, the values I want are in EGr:

```
EG = la.eigvals(H)
EGr = EG.real
```

And EGr is a 1 x 8 array. Example:

```
[ 0.22478205  2.50936963  1.81160702  1.76320129  1.94243736  1.81346264
  1.94243736  1.81346264]
```

How do I write these 8 values in a text/excel file before the loop proceeds on to the next iteration?

At the end of the loop, I wish to have only 1 file with all the values of the loop in it.

Comment: `f=open('file.csv','a'); f.write(', '.join(EGr)); f.close()`

Comment: You have provided unnecessary details in your question. You should just ask "How to write an array in text file or excel?"

Comment: Hi Abdul, thanks for the advice. But I do know how to write an array in a file. What I wanted to learn was how to use a for-loop to add a new line of values to the same text file after each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty basic approach using `csv`:

```
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f) #Uses Excel dialect by default
  for thing in things:
    #...
    EG = la.eigvals(H)
    EGr = EG.real
    writer.writerow(EGr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I get the error:
writer = csv.writer(f)
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined

Edit: Oh, I think I need a csv package. I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: @JoelWong: Sure. If an answer solves your problem, [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: Okay I finally got it to work. I had to add "w" to the Open() command in order to write it. Thanks for the help!